# Selenium Python how to get label name within in child or without in child?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <label for="maeb4bf265013b0ac0">
        <span>name</span>
    </label>
    
    <input type="text" name="maeb4bf265013b0ac0" value="" id="maeb4bf265013b0ac0" style="width: 30%;" />
</form>
```

I am able to grab label following input field by below xpath syntax

```
//form//label[./*[contains(text(),'name')]]/following::input[1]
```

By my label name has lots of variation.

Example:

```
<label>
      name
</label>

<label>
      <div> <span>name</span> </div>
</label>

<label>
      <span>name</span>
</label>
```

For among all cases how can I track label name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dot to find text in xpath.

It can check that if contains `name` in each node of every layer in `label`.

```
//form//label[contains(., 'name')]
```

Comment: Is it possible to track like whatever you get this word name in form then take the next input field ?

Comment: Yes, you can add /following-sibling::input[1] at the end.